# Standard User profile gives error for delete task trigger testclass

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have trigger to stop users to delete task except if profile is "System Administrator".

Trigger :

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before delete) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
            TaskTriggerHandler.beforeDelete(trigger.old);
    }
}
```

Handler Class :

```
public with sharing class TaskTriggerHandler {

    public static void beforeDelete(List<Task> tasks) {    
        Id profileId = Userinfo.getProfileId();
        profile profileName = [select Name from Profile where id=:profileid];
        for(Task t1 : tasks){
            if(profilename.Name != 'System Administrator'){
                t1.addError('Task cannot be deleted');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class :

```
@isTest
public class TaskTriggerTest {

    @isTest
    static void testtaskDeletion(){
        Task newtsk = new Task();
        newtsk.Subject = 'Sample';
        newtsk.Status = 'New';
        insert newtsk;
        Profile p =[Select id from Profile where Name = 'Standard User' Limit 1];
        User usr = new User(Alias = 'kaplan', Email='standarduser@xyz.edu',
                            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id,TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
                            UserName='standarduser@xyz.edu');
        system.runAs(usr){
                try{
                    delete newtsk;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    system.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Task cannot be deleted'));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Result :

Assertion Failed

```
16:21:10:964 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [18]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00T1b000006RWbTEAW; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []"|0x532c2782
```

If I put `system.assert(e.getMessage().contains('INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY'));`
Then assertion pass, but trigger and handler class gets 0% code coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the task as an administrator, then tried to delete it as a normal, unprivileged user. You need to have that user create the task:

```
    system.runAs(usr){
        insert newtsk;
        try{
            delete newtsk;
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Task cannot be deleted'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dang it, Thank you so much.

Comment: @Eklavya You're welcome! It's an easy mistake to make.